# Displaying news with javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll

I keep coming up against this issue. Displaying news on a website. And I'd like to come up with a solution to use like a template, something I can just drop on a site easily.

The solution I keep seeing is an iframe with javascript to scroll the content. However, I'm really opposed to the idea of using iframes, I think the time for those has passed.

I want to use JS without a framework, because it disallows using other frameworks.
Does anyone know where I could find something robust?

(*I'm thinking of using vertical scrolling, but I'm also curious about other solutions*)

Comment: "I want to use JS without a framework, because it disallows using other frameworks." How so?

Comment: "displaying news" is a completely vague request. You need to describe the visual presentation and interaction you are wanting to achieve. Also, as Ben hints at, using one JS framework does not preclude you from using another (though typically you'd want to stick with one if you can from a purely file size perspective)

Comment: - If you use a jquery framework for a vertical scroller, you can't use (from my experience) mootools to deal with another task on the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a script that seems to wok well for me, maybe someone else will find this helpful

```
/***********************************************
* Cross browser Marquee II- © Dynamic Drive (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
* Visit http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for this script and 100s more.
***********************************************/

var delayb4scroll=1000; //Specify initial delay before marquee starts to scroll on page (2000=2 seconds)
var marqueespeed=1; //Specify marquee scroll speed (larger is faster 1-10)
var pauseit=1; //Pause marquee onMousever (0=no. 1=yes)?
var tim;
////NO NEED TO EDIT BELOW THIS LINE////////////

var copyspeed=marqueespeed;
var pausespeed=(pauseit==0)? copyspeed: 0;
var actualheight='';

function scrollmarquee(){
    //document.write(parseInt(cross_marquee.style.top));
        //if (parseInt(cross_marquee.style.top)>(actualheight*(-1)+8)) {
    if (document.getElementById('track').value == "") {
        if (parseInt(cross_marquee.style.top)>(actualheight*(-1)+8)) {
            cross_marquee.style.top=parseInt(cross_marquee.style.top)-copyspeed+"px";
            //alert(actualheight);
        }
        else {
            //alert(parseInt(marqueeheight));
            cross_marquee.style.top=parseInt(marqueeheight)-8+"px";
        }
    }
}

//on mouse out
function mouse_out() {
    clearTimeout(tim);
    scrollmarquee;
}

//init()
function initializemarquee(){
    cross_marquee=document.getElementById("vmarquee");
    cross_marquee.style.top=0;
    marqueeheight=document.getElementById("marqueecontainer").offsetHeight;
    actualheight=cross_marquee.offsetHeight;
    if (window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Netscape/7")!=-1){ //if Opera or Netscape 7x, add scrollbars to scroll and exit
        cross_marquee.style.height=marqueeheight+"px";
        cross_marquee.style.overflow="scroll";
        return
    }
    setTimeout('lefttime=setInterval("scrollmarquee()",55)', delayb4scroll);
}

//event listener
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", initializemarquee, false);
}
else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onload", initializemarquee);
}
else if (document.getElementById) {
    window.onload=initializemarquee;
}
```

the html:

```
<!-- scroll -->
<div id="marqueecontainer" onMouseover="copyspeed=pausespeed" onMouseout="copyspeed=marqueespeed">
<div id="vmarquee" class="vmarquee_content">
    <!--YOUR SCROLL CONTENT HERE-->
</div>
</div>
<input id="track" name="track" type="hidden" value="">
```

and the css:

```
#marqueecontainer{
    position: relative;
    width: 250px; /*marquee width */

    height: 150px; /*marquee height */
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
    padding: 2px;
    padding-left: 4px;
}
.scroll_div {
    border:solid 1px #3366FF;
    width: 260px;
    width/**/: 280px !important;
}
.vmarquee_content {
    position:absolute;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: can't initializing two or more scroller at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Why don´t you take a div insert an other div an give the second div a nagative top value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toTop(top_value)
{
  if (top_value == 0)
  { document.getElementById('news').css.top = '0'; }

  document.getElementById('news').css.top = '-5px';
}
window.setTimeout('toTop(1)', 100);
window.setTimeout('toTop(0)', 10000);
</script>
```

This is untested, but I´ve done it this way.